# What is name we need to use for endofunction if in its definition endomorphism were not in the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory

> An endofunction (or self-mapping or other variation) is an endomorphism in the category of sets, that is a function from a set X to X itself.

Ok, what new names we have now for

- endofunction

if endomorphism **were not** in the category of sets for endofunction definition?

1. we can no longer use as label the word "endofunction" because

   - we have a general category and not a specific category (category of Sets in this context)
   - endomorphism change its name into morphism $f : x \to x$

Comment: I don't understand.  They're called endomorphisms generally, and I suppose you could say endofunction for sets (though I've never seen this).  What's the problem?

Comment: @Randall I think he might be asking about the terminology for non-concrete categories.

Comment: "Endomorphisms"

Comment: If you tell me that you never seen *endofunction for sets* why there is no a name of this possibility?

Comment: I mean, I've personally never seen it, but I'm not everyone....

Comment: I read this **In general, we can talk about endomorphisms in *any* category. In the category of sets, endomorphisms are functions from a set S to itself**  So, if we restrict endomorphism into Category of sets only we can call this endomorphisms *endofunctions*. So for any category term correct is *endomorphism*? But, I would not have used it in definition for endofunction the same 'endomorphism' term, this confuse me

Comment: Yes, "endomorphism" is a perfectly general term in any category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematics uses some well-established cliches for giving definitions. One of the most commonly used cliches is following. Let $X$ be a concept, denoted by an informal symbol (for example, english word) $x$, which is defined for mathematical objects of type $\mathcal{T}$ (I use the word "type" in informal meaning here, but I guess it may be formalized), and let $O$ be a mathematical object of type $\mathcal{T}$. Let also $y$ be a new informal symbol. Then we may produce a new "definition" (which is in fact an informal metamathematical notation):
$$
\text{Definition. $y$ is $x$ in $O$.}
$$
After the definition is given, every partial case of the concept $X$ in $O$ we may call equivalently $y$ or $x$ (when it is obvious from a context that we "talk about $O$").

In your question: 
$$
X=\text{a concept of endomorphism};
$$ 
$$
x=\text{"endomorphism" (word)};
$$
$$
\mathcal{T}=\text{all categories (or some variation of this notion, depending on foundations)};
$$
$$
O=\mathbf{Set};
$$
$$
y=\text{"endofunction" (word)}
$$

Endomorphisms are defined for any category, they are simply morphisms from an object to itself. So as objects of $\mathbf{Set}$ are sets and morphisms are functions, after giving this definition we may say that endofunction is a function from a set to itself.

I apologize to the logic experts if my answer uses self-made notions, I just try to explain how the definitions work "in practice".